# How to fetch value with Cassandra PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, cql3

I am using a PHP PDO driver for an application that uses Apache Cassandra and I cannot fetch the information I need. Is anything obviously wrong?

```
$db = new PDO('cassandra:host=localhost;port=9160');
$db->exec("USE project");
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT fname FROM users WHERE email=:em;");
$st->bindValue(':em', 'email1@gmail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
print_r($st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Nothing is printed to the window. The table users was created with the email column as the primary key. I had no trouble inserting and updating information to the users table in my app, but still cannot figure out how to fetch single values successfully. Similarly, when I fetchAll() with some query I can print the arrays (rows) to the screen but cannot index them to grab specific values. Maybe there is some detail about cassandra that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Check the return values of each method.
2. Check if there is an error after executing the statement.
3. Check the error log of your php interpreter.

```php
$db = new PDO('cassandra:host=localhost;port=9160');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); 
$db->exec("USE project");
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT fname FROM users WHERE email=:em;");

if ($st == false) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo())
    exit;
}

if ($st->bindValue(':em', 'email1@gmail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR) == false) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo())
    exit;
}

if ($st->execute() == false) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo())
    exit;
}

print_r($st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I used YACassandraPDO. Unfortunately when use it with php 5.4 I get error 502. Decided to write his or her library that allowed to work with Cassandra binary protocol without experiencing similar problems.

In the future, I plan to speed it up.

Maybe [it will help you](http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/). Syntax like PDO.